# How to repeat an angular element starting on index 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want my `ng-repeat` to start after *position 1*, so I did this, but it doesn't work. Should I crop the array before painting it or is there a native way to do this?

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", [])
  .controller("MainController", control_fun);

function control_fun() {
  this.items = ["position 0", "position 1", "position 2", "position 3"];
};
```

```html
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter: item > 1">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are running angular >= 1.4.0, you can use `limitTo : limit: begin` filter

`<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | limitTo : ctrl.items.length : 1}}</div>`

Check this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/u9q9Q3sr6O8moWNwgadK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the array and use rest to iterate

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items.slice(1) track by $index">
```

**Demo:**

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myapp",[])
.controller("MainController", control_fun);

function control_fun(){
  this.items = ["position 0", "position 1", "position 2", "position 3"];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items.slice(1) track by $index">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```